# Why can you hide the loading indicator image on SPLongOperation

Tags: 2010, 2013, splongoperation

A few months ago I started developing for SharePoint and since the very first day I have a - very important - open question.

If you use a long running operation a loading indicator image is rendered and there is also this (epic) feature that you can disable the image if you click on it.

Does anyone has any idea why someone would add this kind of feature? You can't even bring it back if you click again.

Maybe a Microsoft employee reads this and can answer that or maybe even post the corresponding commit message ;)

Obviously this is just a question out of curiosity and not really important - but as I said it's nagging at me since the beginning... :)

[image: SPLongRunningOperation hover]

[image: SPLongRunningOperation after click]

Answer (score 1):

Just thoughts here:

I haven't tested the behavior of other SharePoint's pop-up messages, but this is probably based on the same technology as they are. This could possibly be seen from elements of the page.

Pop-up messages in another cases, such as pretty usual "Loading..." or similar can be sometimes seen when e.g. when entering to page's edit mode. These messages might in some unusual cases disturb the user, which is why they could be easily hid.

So why create different pop-up messages when you have one ready, which can be called.